# Overriding joomla session variables for form handling

Tags: session, joomla, session-variables, payment-gateway

I have a joomla website with plethora theme. This is the link to the website where I'm facing problems. http://miraghotels.com/joomjob/membership/planadd?step=2
The form on this link is processed somewhere and an array of variables referring to the form fields and their values is stored in the Joomla session. The problem is that I want to change/override the value of a parameter which is actually in the array variable of the session. To explain this, I'm attaching this code.

```
$planChosen = $session->get('planChosen', 0, 'register');
```

First of all, what syntax is this session following? I get a different ouput from just

```
$session->get('planChosen').
```

Ok now, when I ouput this variable($planChosen), I get the following output:

```
Array ( [planname3] => Basic 
[planperiod3] => 15 Days 
[plancredit3] => 5 
[price3] => 0 
[plan_id] => 4
[planname4] => Premium 
[planperiod4] => 3 Months 
[plancredit4] => 25 
[price4] => 50 
[gateway] => paypal 
[option] => com_joomjob 
[task] => guest.grabplaninfo 
[2d13d7c9e4ffff248cf29092b199f5b2] => 1 )
```

Now what I want to know is that where is this session stored i.e. where can I find the file where these items are processed in the session.
Secondly, if I want to override a value for e.g. change the value of "gateway" from "paypal" to "moneybookers", how can I achieve that? I tried the following code but no luck:

```
$string="('planChosen', 0, 'register')[\"gateway\"]";
$session->set($string, "moneybookers");
```

Please help me out with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this from Joomla.org website
The following code gets the current session then sets the value of the session variable 'myvar' to 'helloworld'.

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set( 'myvar', 'helloworld' );
```

The session variable can be retrieved later in a similar way.

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
echo 'Session variable myvar has value: ' . $session->get( 'myvar', 'empty' );
```

So if you used this code to set paypal as payment gateway

```
$session->set( 'gateway', 'paypal' );
```

Now if you want moneybookers you can override paypal by

```
$session->clear('gateway');
$session->set( 'gateway', 'moneybookers' );
```

And your session data are saved in database by default unless you changed it to files in the global configuration area. So #__sessions has all your session data.

EDIT:
In that case you can do like this

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set( 'planChosen', $planChosen );//store array in session  variable
//Now you have entire array in this session variable which contains paypal as payment gateway
// Suppose you want to update it then use the code below 
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$planChosen = $session->get( 'planChosen' );
unset($planChosen[$gateway]);
$planChosen["gateway"] = "moneybookers";
$session->set('planChosen',$planChosen);
```

Comment: Hi Amit, the thing is that the "gateway" variable is a part of an array and you can't directly change that.. I tried your method but it doesn't work. Also the variables stored in session are not there in the tables, I tried searching but the session table has just some raw encrypted data, nothing else that signals to my requirements. Any other options?

Comment: @MuddassirAhmed I have updated the code. have a relook.

Comment: Your code worked a bit. Now I'm getting another array containing the "gateway"="moneybookers" in my previous array i.e. the "gateway" key is not overridden rather it is duplicated in another array which is stored in the original planChosen.
 Like this:
Array ( [planname3] => Basic [planperiod3] => 15 Days [plancredit3] => 5 [price3] => 0 [plan_id] => 4 [planname4] => Premium [planperiod4] => 3 Months [plancredit4] => 25 [price4] => 50 [gateway] => paypal [option] => com_joomjob [task] => guest.grabplaninfo [d22cbec0b08bbfcf427114d822b282c9] => 1 [0] => Array ( [gateway] => moneybookers ) )

Comment: What I want is that the when I use the following code:

`$session->get('planChosen', 0, 'register')`

I should get the output with the "gateway=paypal" value replaced by "moneybookers"

Comment: .Thanks lot man.. That solves my session problem . However, I discovered now that the form values that are being retained by this session are not actually stored in the database through the session variable itself.. There is some other file that is processing the form fields and storing them in database.

Comment: You are welcome man. Its good that in the process you discovered something more.